# @ComponentScanning-Error at Spring Boot Application with IntelliJ not with Eclipse

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I'm working on a **Spring Boot**-Application which is using *Maven* for build management. I have imported this application to **IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 16.1**. I got the following error if I run my *main*-class:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.3.RELEASE)

Appl - 2016-09-01 08:04:31,642 [main] INFO  c.w.application.Application -  -  - Starting Application on mycomputer with PID 23345 (/pathToApplication/target/classes started by user in /pathtoapplication)
Appl - 2016-09-01 08:04:31,742 [main] DEBUG c.w.application.Application -  -  - Running with Spring Boot v1.2.3.RELEASE, Spring v4.1.6.RELEASE
Appl - 2016-09-01 08:04:38,519 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication -  -  - Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer due to internal class not found. This can happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:51) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:190) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:148) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:124) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:318) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.applicationpackage.application.Application.main(Application.java:43) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1967) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:488) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:534) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:677) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:621) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:968) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:257) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:246) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:227) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:158) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:147) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:119) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:45) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
...
```

The code of this method (include error-point *Application.java line 43* out of above message) is:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.applicationpackage")
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Application.context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        Application.context.registerShutdownHook();
  }
  ...
}
```

There is no quicktip or error on this line of code displayed.

If I import it to **Eclipse Neo** it runs without any errors and I can access my web-application. If I run **Maven install** (e.g. out of IntelliJ) then the application is started for some test cases well, too. So it seems that the error is caused by an setting of *IntelliJ*. In *project structure* menu there are no problems displayed and the *Spring Application Context* is filled with Application (no "context-less classes" displayed).

Comment: maybe your problem is related where your jars are placed, maybe intellij is going to find them in other place.

Comment: Did you put your `Application` class in the default package?

Comment: @LipingHuang It is placed in a full-named package e.g. com.my.application.Application.java

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

Select:File -> Project Structure->Modules->Dependencies

Find:tomcat-embed-core (this jar package default is provided, change to compile)

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing this dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: This dependency is already added. If it is missing Eclipse would not be able to start too.

Comment: on the Maven Projects tool bar click on "Reimport All Maven Projects"

Comment: It changed nothing. A complete reimport of the project changed nothing too. It seems like it's a setting-error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (application running in eclipse, not in intellij).

In my pom.xml tomcat-embed-jasper and javax.servlet had scope provided.

I commented out these scopes and now everything works fine.